# specifying required patterns for form inputs

Tags: php, html

i'm a beginner in html and i was wondering how i could make a required pattern for each input. The email part is working but concerning the Student ID, i need it to be 9 digits and starts with S and rest is numbers for example: S00024432 Or S00023324 but not SS00002424242 OR S00005421M and for the phone number, i need it to be 8 digits all numbers ofcourse.

```
<label for="sid" accesskey="i">Student ID</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input name="sid" type="text" id="sid" size="10" pattern="[s]*[0-9]" required />
</div>
<br>
<div>
    <label for="email" accesskey="E">Email</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input name="email" type="email" id="email" pattern="^[A-Za-z0-9](([_\.\-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)@([A-Za-z0-9]+)(([\.\-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)\.([A-Za-z]{2,})$" required />
</div>
<br>
<div>
    <label for="phone" accesskey="p">Phone No.</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input name="phone" type="tel" id="phone" size="8" pattern="(0-9)(0-9)(0-9)" required />
</div>
<br>
```

Also here i have a section input that is a "**number**" but im still able to plugin values that i enter, i want it only selected by the increase/decrease arrow. It would be great if you guide me through. Thanks

```
<div>
    <label for="section" accesskey="o">Section</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input name="section" type="number" id="section" min="1" max="9" required />
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way

For Student ID:

```
    pattern="^S[0-9]{8}$"
```

For Number :

```
    pattern="^[0-9]{8}$"
```

**EDIT:**

```
  pattern="^(S|s)[0-9]{8}$" //for both capital S and smaller s
```

[image]

[image]

**As Per Comment:**

```
$('input[type="number"]').keypress(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: what if i wanted the S to be both capital and small letters? i tested your code and its working .

Comment: great, would be awsome if you helped me with the section also, i added a picture in the main post. I want to be able to only choose the section numbers from the up/down arrows . Currently i can use the arrows and enter it manually through the keyboard.

Comment: @Sam, ok i will do that for you soon

Answer (score 0):

Your student ID pattern means "any number of 's' characters and one digit". What you want is `S[0-9]{8,8}`. If phone number can only be 8 digits and nothing else, a corresponding regexp is `[0-9]{8,8}`.

Comment: for the student id, it will make the student id require the S at start only? and one S only? rest are numbers?

Comment: tried it works, thank you teyras, any idea how i can make the section code work?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what exactly you want it to do. What are "increase/descrease arrows" and what do you mean by selecting the section ang plugging in values?

Comment: i will post a picture now.

Comment: added the pic of section, in my case i can both input a number using the keyboard and the arrows. i wanna make it only arrows.